# MS Access crashes when trying to close down a connection to Blackbaud's Raiser's Edge API

Tags: vba, ms-access, blackbaud

I am the IT department of a Non-Profit organization. I have a question today which might be too specialized for this forum and I hope I do not waste my time writing it up. We are using Blackbaud's 'Raiser's Edge' (RE) Software (written in VB6 and VB.net as far as I know) to keep track of our membership and donations. We have an MS Access application (have been using it since before we got RE) to process donations and for now I want to keep it and only do minor changes to adapt it to the new software.

The MS Access program is now doing a few calls to the RE API which work great. To login and establish a connection I have to create a new 'REAPI' object and use it for other API calls. That `REAPI` object has a method called: `SignOutOnTerminate` which needs to be set to TRUE when creating that object. It is supposed to kill all connections to RE once my application closes. There is no regular `.close` method.

Once I create the object I can do work as many times as I want and there is no problem at all as far as I can see.

However when trying to close the application or set the object to nothing (`Set REAPI = Nothing`) Access crashes immediately (It fades out and I get the message that Windows is looking for a solution to the problem. Then Access closes and restarts itself.)

It is more annoying and unprofessional then hindering production but I want to fix it.

The App was developed on Windows 7 64-bit with Access 2010 32-bit. It was tested on  Windows XP with Office 2003 or 2007 machines (32-bit) and behaves the same way.

I have posted this problem already on 2 Blackbaud forums and tried a suggested a work around which did not work (kill the process with a shell command and then set the object to nothing). Hopefully I will get more answers soon.

I tried to just exclude the `SignOutOnTerminate` when creating the object. But got the same behavior.

I looked in the Event Manager --> Application Log and found the Crash. It reported that access crashed because of this dll: C:\Windows\System32\MSVBVM60.dll  (It is actually located in the SysWos64 folder as it is a 32-bit application).

Looking up this error I found some suggestions to replace it with an earlier version of the dll, the one which ships with XP. I found a file and tried the suggestion but it still crashed. The error log reported the older version number as faulting so I registered it correctly.

I also created a case with Blackbaud but the rep did not know what the problem is and did not have MS Access installed. He is trying to get his support team to install it for him so he can test and investigate this error.

The last suspicion I have is that the API is causing the error and my code is fine.

But before I make this assumption and until I get my answer from Blackbaud I want to do a final check, but I have run out of ideas for further trouble shooting and resorted to pose this problem in this forum.

Any Ideas?

Comment: it seems to me that  Blackbaud's 'Raiser's Edge' (RE) Software is not cleaning up its ressources properly.  
SignOutOnTerminate : seems to me, that they will SignOut when the object gets terminated, in .NET its get terminated by the garbage collector but in VBA there is no garbage collector, so the termination behaves differently.
It would be better if the API had an explicit .close method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I realise that this is an old thread and if you have solved this by now then that is great. However this  is a known issue with The Raiser's Edge API. If you use .NET with RE's API (which is COM based) there is definitely some resource that is not cleaned up properly. At one point I suspected that it was something to with making use of RE's graphical interface i.e. by calling the regular login method to log you into RE. However even if you log in to RE using the "as a server" method supplying the user name and password it still crashes on exiting the application.

We have an installer that sets up credentials in RE. The installer is in .NET and accesses the RE API. We now show a message just before the end of the application telling users to ignore the impending crash... Not a great solution by any means.

Comment: Thanks @zeiddev for this confirmation of my suspicion. I hope Blackbaud will fix this at some point.